# Typescript React: Do I have to specify arguments for the super class constructor. And what arguments would that be?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, super

Hello so the whole thing is not really clear for me, I still am confused on which specific argument my constructor actually wants. If it is obvious to you could you tell me what the constructor arguments for `super()` and the `constructor()` would have to be?

```
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./ScriptEditor.module.scss";
import { IScriptEditorProps } from "./IScriptEditorProps";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogType,
  DialogFooter
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dialog";
import {
  DefaultButton,
  PrimaryButton
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";
import { loadStyles } from "@microsoft/load-themed-styles";
require("./overrides.css");

export default class ScriptEditor extends React.Component<
  IScriptEditorProps,
  any
> {
  **constructor(IScriptEditorProps, any) {
    super(IScriptEditorProps, any);**

    this._showDialog = this._showDialog.bind(this);
    this._closeDialog = this._closeDialog.bind(this);
    this._cancelDialog = this._cancelDialog.bind(this);
    this._onScriptEditorTextChanged = this._onScriptEditorTextChanged.bind(
      this
    );

    const uiFabricCSS: string = `
    .pzl-bgColor-themeDark, .pzl-bgColor-themeDark--hover:hover {
      background-color: "[theme:themeDark, default:#005a9e]";
    }
    `;
    loadStyles(uiFabricCSS);
    this.state = {
      showDialog: false
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.setState({ script: this.props.script, loaded: this.props.script });
  }
  private _showDialog() {
    this.setState({ showDialog: true });
  }

  private _closeDialog() {
    this.setState({ showDialog: false });
    this.props.save(this.state.script);
  }

  private _cancelDialog() {
    this.props.save(this.state.loaded);
    this.setState({ showDialog: false, script: this.state.loaded });
  }

  private _onScriptEditorTextChanged(text: string) {
    this.setState({ script: text });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IScriptEditorProps> {
    const viewMode = (
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.script }}></span>
    );
```

.
.
.

I kept out the `return` because i figured it wouldn't be relevant to my question.

So far i have changed a few things back and forth but i barely understand the constructor at all and am really irritated and what parameters my `constructor` and the `super()` class wants.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `props` to a react class constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    ..............
}
```

Comment: I'm really new to react and typescript in general. Where exactly are my props?

Comment: `props` are there automatically when you extend `React.Component` you don't need to define it, you just need to pass it in to the constructor like I wrote in the answer. does that make sense?

Comment: oh ok thank you very much i thought i have to assign them.

Comment: Also, you don't need a constructor just to bind your actions, if you switch your functions to arrow functions like this `_showDialog = (args) => {...}` they are binded automatically. Hope I'm not confusing you.

Comment: I'll try to implement it and if i fail i will revert but thank you !

Comment: @slurm what is "this"?

Comment: oh i updated it and i think there is a Problem where I put the ** `constructor(IScriptEditorProps, any) {
    super(IScriptEditorProps, any);` **